# Advanced file and folder search for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, windows-search, file-search

Is there a way to add advanced options when doing a search on Windows 7? for example how to exclude certain folder, or exclude certain file types. Any software that could help with this sort of advanced search? or maybe there are search options that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Related: [How to easily use Windows 7 search advanced options?](http://superuser.com/questions/133423/how-to-easily-use-windows-7-search-advanced-options) and [Quickly filter file types or folders in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/66516/quickly-filter-file-types-or-folders-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can ADD extra options but if you're looking for a separate search tool here's a thread that talks about alternative search programs:

https://superuser.com/questions/135423/whats-a-good-alternative-to-windows-search-for-files-and-folders